# socket: too many open files

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, network-programming

I am trying to make an HTTP server in C, but when I run the program it sometimes reports a runtime error:

> bind: address already in use

Now it is giving:

> socket: too many open files

Here is the code:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<unistd.h>

struct Server{
    int domain;
    int service_type;
    int protocol;
    __u_long interface;
    int port;
    int backlog;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int socket;
    void (*launch)(struct Server *server);
};


struct Server server_constructor(int domain, int service, int protocol, __u_long interface, int port, int backlog, void (* launch)(struct Server* server)){
    struct Server server;
    server.domain = domain;
    server.service_type = service;
    server.protocol = protocol;
    server.interface = interface;
    server.port = port;
    server.backlog = backlog;
    
    server.address.sin_port = htons(server.port);
    server.address.sin_family = server.domain;
    server.address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(server.interface);
    memset(server.address.sin_zero, '\0', sizeof server.address.sin_zero);

    server.socket = socket(server.domain, server.service_type, server.protocol);
    if(server.socket < 0){
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int bind_stat = bind(server.socket, (struct sockaddr*)&server.address, sizeof(server.address));
    if(bind_stat < 0){
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Binding Sucessful\n");
    int listen_stat = listen(server.socket, server.backlog);
    if(listen_stat < 0){
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Listening on port %d\n", server.port);
    server.launch = launch;
}


void launch(struct Server *server){
    int addr_len = sizeof(server->address);
    char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\nHello world!";
    char buffer[300000] = {0};
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n++++++++++++++ Listening for connections ++++++++++++++\n");

        int client_socket = accept(server->socket, (struct sockaddr * )& server->address, (socklen_t*)&addr_len);
        if(client_socket < 0){
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        read(client_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        write(client_socket, hello, strlen(hello));
        printf("\n++++++++++++++++ Response message sent ++++++++++++++++\n");
    }
    
    close(server->socket);

}


int main(){

    struct Server server = server_constructor(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0, INADDR_ANY, 9988, 5, launch);

    server.launch(&server);

    return 0;
}
```

It was working before when everything was in `int main()`, but now errors are appearing and it is exiting with a segmentation fault.

Please help me out.

Comment: `char buffer[300000]` looks like a very large local buffer. Why so large?

Comment: You need to `close(client_socket)` when you're done with that client.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i am accepting a http request i dont want it to overflow in case of a post request.

Comment: `memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer)); read(client_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));` tries to read 0 bytes.

Comment: @Barmar did that but when i am running it in vs code it gives bind address already in use and when i run it on terminal it gives socket too many open files

Comment: You need to use the `SO_REUSEADDR` socket option to prevent "address already in use" if you try to restart the server soon after killing it.

Comment: @TusharSingh there is no buffer size you can specify that a client cannot maliciously or accidentally overwhelm.  A robust server cannot assume that it can fit entire client requests into statically-allocated buffers.

Comment: @TusharSingh using a large stack buffer is not the best way to handle http clients. At the very least, you should be dynamically allocating the buffer per client, and consider using a buffer that can grow depending on how much data the client actually sends so you are not wasting memory unnecessarily, and cap it so a client can't overwhelm the server.

Answer (score 2):

You're never closing the client sockets, so you're eventually running into your open file descriptor limit. Put `close(client_socket)` after you send the response.

Another problem is using `strlen(buffer)` when you call `read()`. Since you just zeroed out the buffer, its length is `0`, so you don't read anything. Use `sizeof buffer - 1` (subtracting 1 to leave the null terminator at the end).

```
void launch(struct Server *server){
    int addr_len = sizeof(server->address);
    char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/plain\n\nHello world!";
    char buffer[300000] = {0};
    while (1)
    {
        printf("\n++++++++++++++ Listening for connections ++++++++++++++\n");

        int client_socket = accept(server->socket, (struct sockaddr * )& server->address, (socklen_t*)&addr_len);
        if(client_socket < 0){
            perror("accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof buffer - 1);
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        write(client_socket, hello, strlen(hello));
        printf("\n++++++++++++++++ Response message sent ++++++++++++++++\n");
        close(client_socket);
    }
}
```

There's also no point to `close(server->socket);`. This line will never be reached because it's after the infinite `while (1)` loop. The only way out of the loop is if `accept()` gets an error, then it calls `exit()`.

Comment: `read(client_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));` is like `read(client_socket, buffer, 0);`.  It will not read anything.  Suggest  `read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);`

Comment: That is the point that the server runs forever so that it keeps accepting the requests from any possible client.

Comment: The socket error is coming from server_constructor function where i am creating the server socket.

Comment: @TusharSingh The error that chux pointed out is unrelated to the error. It just prevents you from reading anything from the socket.

Comment: You don't need to null-terminate the buffer if you tell `printf()` how many bytes are actually in the buffer (ie, the return value of `read()`), eg: `ssize_t numBytes = read(client_socket, buffer, sizeof buffer); if (numBytes > 0) { printf("%.*s\n", (int) numBytes, buffer); }`